# Patent expiration date with multiple publications

Tags: law, patent-lifetime, us20120221930

I was wondering what a patents `Priority date` is? If its set to 1997 and it has been published 6 times (the last publish was 2012) when does it expire?

The patent I am talking about is [US20120221930](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120221930?dq=load%20web%20pages%20in%20background&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bdGzUKflAq-a0QXz64HACQ&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCA).

Answer (score 5):

US20120221930 is a pending application - not a granted patent.  It has a lengthy history as set out at the beginning of the description:

"This application is a continuation of co-pending U.S. patent application Ser. No. 12/628,465, filed on Dec. 1, 2009, which claims priority under 35 U.S.C. §120 as a continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 10/446,623, filed on May 28, 2003, now issued as U.S. Pat. No. 7,647,550, which is a continuation of U.S. patent application Ser. No. 08/712,586, filed on Sep. 13, 1996, now issued as U.S. Pat. No. 6,584,498, the entire disclosures of which are incorporated by reference."

It should expire on September 13, 2016 - BUT!  And there are a lot of buts.  First the application must be examined and a patent granted.  Then any renewal fees owing must be paid. If these happen then the term is calculated to be 20 years from the first filing date - September 13, 1996.  There is even another but.  The term may be extended if there is a delay of more than three years in processing in the US patent office - calculated from the date the of the filing of this continuation, August 30,2012.

You can keep track of the application on the PAIR system at the USPTO.

Cheers

Comment: How does the CIP or Con of this patent analyzed? Do they extend the entire application or just the portion mentioned on CIP/Con ?